# Issue with arc4random implementation

Tags: objective-c, random

I'm trying to get a random number from an array using `arc4random`. I have tried everything I can think of but I just can't get it to work as every time it just returns 81 which is the number of items in the array. I just need it to select a random number from however many items are in the array. This is my code:

```
 _equations = @[@"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"9", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"18", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"27", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"36", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"45", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"54", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"63", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"72", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"" ,@"81" ];
 NSUInteger randomEquationNo = arc4random() % [_equations count];
 int index = arc4random_uniform(81);
 id randomNo = nil;
 if ([_equations count] > 0){
    int index = arc4random()%[_equations count];
    randomNo = [_equations objectAtIndex:index];
 }

NSString  *e1 = @"8+2-9=";
NSString  *e2 = @"3x5-7=";
//81 of those strings

if ((index = 1)) {
    _equationsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",e1];
}
if ((index = 2)) {
    _equationsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",e2];
//81 of those if statements
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: That's not code, that's a random (!) collection of bits of code. Can you provide the actual (minimal, complete, verifiable ) code you use, how you log its return value, and what you get?

Comment: @jcaron added more code

Comment: It makes even less sense. None of the code you added has any relevance whatsoever to your question. And obviously, `if ((index = 1))` means "assign 1 to `index`, then execute the code below", not "if the value of `index` is 1, execute the code below". The equality operator is `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I worked it out! I got rid of all my previous attempts to get it to work and logged it to see if the issue was with `arc4random` or something else. And it was with something else and it turned out it was with my if statements because as jcaron pointed out, I was assigned index a value of 1 instead of comparing it. This was the code I ended up with:

```
int index = (arc4random() % (81));
    NSString* indexLog = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Equation number is %i", index];
    NSLog(indexLog);

NSString  *e1 = @"8+2-9=";
NSString  *e2 = @"3x5-7=";
//81 of those strings

if (index == 1) {
    _equationsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",e1];
}
if (index == 2) {
    _equationsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",e2];
//81 of those if statements
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your code but if I may, I suggest you to read this [post](http://nshipster.com/random/), specially on the section *How Do I Pick a Random Element from an NSArray?*

```
if ([array count] > 0) {
  id obj = array[arc4random_uniform([array count])];
}
```